# How to create many new columns that are the products of selected two columns in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe look like this:

| a | b | c | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I call the column list XX=[a,b,c], YY=[A,B,C]

And I want to multiply every variable in XX to every variable in YY and create a new dataframe look like this:

| a | b | c | A | B | C | a_A | a_B | a_C | b_A | b_B | b_C | c_A | c_B | c_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6 |

For example: the second value of a_A, which is 4, is the product of the second value of a, which is 4, and the second value of A, which is 1.

I've tried the following code:

```
for i in XX:
    for j in YY:
        data[i+'_'+j] = data.apply(lambda x: x[i] * x[j], axis=1)
```

My code works, but it took forever to finish my calculation. To be honest, I haven't got what I want since my really data has 94 XX variables and 8 YY variables, I need to create 94*8= 752 new columns. And I have over 2million rows of data. The kernel died every time i tired my code.

How to solve this problem and create the new dataframe efficiently? I appreciate your great help! Thanks

Comment: There is a type in your expected result. (One 7 to much, one 9 to litle.)

Comment: Yes, there is 7/8/9 in place of 4/5/6 (which doesn't change the logic but makes it confusing)

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I've revised.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) combined with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
from itertools import product
XX=['a','b','c']
YY=['A','B','C']

out = df.join(pd.concat({f'{a}_{b}': df[a]*df[b]
                         for a,b in product(XX, YY)}, axis=1))
```

output:

```
   a  b  c  A  B  C  a_A  a_B  a_C  b_A  b_B  b_C  c_A  c_B  c_C
0  1  2  3  1  1  1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3    3
1  4  5  6  1  1  1    4    4    4    5    5    5    6    6    6
```